# How to get updated content from local HTML file to display in WebView in UWP app?

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

I have a UWP application where i have one folder which has multiple image files and  HTML page which renders all images. This images are downloaded based on the listview item selections. I am using WebView control to render HTML page in my app.

I am able to display the HTML page loads correctly along with all JS and images, but the problem is that it shows the same images even though the images in the folder changed.

Here is how i am loading html page

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    if (e.Parameter != null)
    {
        webView360.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appx-web:///local/Image360Viewer/index.html"));
    }
}
```

For example, Load only simple HTML with "Hello" in body then change to "Hello World" from text editor when application is still running then navigate to your view again, it should show "Hello World" but it will still show "Hello" which was the version when application started.

Edit: I have HTML and image in project folder structure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Where're the images and HTML file? If these files are in app local folder. You need to use the Uri like this: `"ms-appdata:///local/Image360Viewer/index.html"`

The `ms-appx-web` URI scheme refers to a file that comes from your app's package, not app local folder.

Please read [URI schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes) for more information.

Comment: I have edited the question with image. Please check.

Comment: @Auneell Your screenshot confirms my guess. You're referring to the files that from your app's package folder. They're read-only. What you need to do is copy these files to app data folder. For example, the [ApplicationData.LocalFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241621). See [file-access-permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you tell me where should I manually copy paste my folder which then can be used in all the build? I copied to package folder AppData but that doesn't seem to be right way

Comment: @Auneell By programming,you need to use [StorageFile.CopyAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.copyasync).